# Filter array of object, with key value in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, filter

I am trying to display some object by filtering it

In my programm, i receive bunch of object in an Array.

those array contain object with key and value..

I want to order those array depend on some key that I want.

For exemple there the structure of one object :

```
Object {
​​
assembly_id: 1234
​​
installation_id: "29537"
​​
interval: "600"
​​
itedef_id: "239"
​​
item_id: "14485"
​​
object_id: "114"
​​
name: "moa"
​​
}
​​
```

My goal is to rearrange the array and have arrays of object that is rearrange by object_id.

i already achieve this frst part by using this function :

```
 transformArray(array: Array<any>, field: string) {
    if (array) {
      const groupedObj = array.reduce((prev, cur) => {
        if (!prev[cur[field]]) {
          prev[cur[field]] = [cur];
        } else {
          prev[cur[field]].push(cur);
        }
        return prev;
      }, {});
      return Object.keys(groupedObj).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedObj[key] }));
    }
    return [];
  }
```

with that, I am able to have this output :

`Array(7) :[ ​ 0: Object { key: "114", value: (11) […] } ​ 1: Object { key: "115", value: (10) […] } ​ 2: Object { key: "116", value: (5) […] } ​ 3: Object { key: "117", value: (15) […] } ​ 4: Object { key: "118", value: (13) […] } ​ 5: Object { key: "119", value: (12) […] } ​ 6: Object { key: "120", value: (10) […] } ]`

Key are the different 'object_id' that all Object have, and inside each object we have an array of objects that have the same object_id.

My issue now is that inside those object of array of object, some object have same 'assembly_id' (and after that, filter them  by item_id then by interval)

So I would like to filter that aswell.
and have in ouptut something like that:

```
Array :[
​
0: Object { objectIdKey: "114", value [assemblyIdKey: 2, value: [object...], assemblyIdKey: 3, value. [object...] }
​
1: Object { objectIdKey: "115", value: [assemblyIdKey: 5, value: [object...], assemblyIdKey: 4, value. [object...] }
​
​
2: Object { key: "objectIdKey", value: [assemblyIdKey: 6, value: [object...], assemblyIdKey: 7, value. [object...] }
]
```

I hop that I've been clear enough, any tips or advice or clue is welcome.

Cheers

I tried to use the transformArray function on the second level but it create bunch of array. 1 array by object_id and that's not what I want.

Comment: Please provide a plaintext [mre] others can copy and paste into their own IDEs to demonstrate your issue and immediately start working on it.  Right now you're giving something like console logs instead of valid object literals, and we only see one input element.  It would be very useful to see a complete and concrete example of desired input/output that captures enough of your use case so that people can use it to test their solution before posting it.

Comment: Yes you're right, let me share input/output and correct structure, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to apply your grouping recursively to the generated arrays, right? I.e. if you grouped by objectIdKey first, the you go through each group and group it again by the next property.

Here is an example:

```js
const data = [
{id: 1, id1: 'a', id2: 1},
{id: 1, id1: 'a', id2: 1},
{id: 1, id1: 'b', id2: 1},
{id: 1, id1: 'b', id2: 1},
{id: 1, id1: 'b', id2: 2},
{id: 1, id1: 'b', id2: 2},
{id: 2, id1: 'a', id2: 1},
]

const groupBy = (a,p) => a.reduce( (g,e) => ({...g, [e[p]]: [...(g[e[p]] ?? []), e] }),{})
const groupByRec = (a,[p, ...ps]) => !p ? a : Object.entries(groupBy(a,p)).map( ([k, v]) => ({[p]:k, value:groupByRec(v, ps)}))
const res = groupByRec(data, ['id', 'id1', 'id2'])

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Grouping the already grouped array, make me confuse.
I'll try our solution that seems to fit perfectly, and let you know, thanks a lot.

Comment: So, after testing, yes that is exactly what I need. Thank you again, recursive filtering was little bit confusing to me.